# How can I edit main header height in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to change my main header height to a normal size. I want to show you 2 picture here. First picture is the live version of my website. Other one is what I want it to become.

PS: Please explain like I'm five because I am a lawyer not a coder, thanks

[this is what is it like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ackt.jpg)

[and I want it to become like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6WZ8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header size depends on different things, e.g. the Theme, the Plug-Ins.

You can change the appearance of your page with css and js.

You have now following options:

1. Install a css change plugin like [this for exemple](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/) and then find
2. Or go to the Theme code.

You must then find the name of id/class/tag of the header. You looking for somethink like

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header logo-left-menu-right" role="banner">
```

Then you must write a css (js is also possible the following excemple is for css ) that makes the header smaller. If you will that the page looks good in different sizes, you should use dynamic size descriptions like %,em,rem.

Something like the following code.

```
#masthead{
   height:10%;
}
```

In some cases the height is protected. Then you can try the !importent statement.

```
#masthead{
   height:10%!importent;
}
```